# __set magic method for sql select statements

Tags: php, oop, magic-methods

In here I'm going to create a class to work with SQL select using PHP __set magic method.My var_dump array return  `array(0) { }` In the browser.What is the error i have did ?

```
class helper{

public function __set($table,$id){

    $dbConfig=array("localhost","itXXXXX","itXXXXX","u?XXXXXXX");
               $pardConfig=new PDO('mysql:host='.$dbConfig[0].';'.'dbname='.$dbConfig[1],$dbConfig[2],$dbConfig[3]);

               $sql=$pardConfig->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".$table."WHERE id=".$id);
               $sql->execute();
               $result=$sql->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
               var_dump($result);
  }
        }

$helper = new helper();
$helper->pard_menu = 99;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the error your query must have produced.

You are missing a whitespace between the table name and the `WHERE` keyword:

```
$sql=$pardConfig->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".$table."WHERE id=".$id);
// HERE ------------------------------------------^
```

*change it to:*

```
$sql=$pardConfig->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".$table." WHERE id=".$id);
```

Comment: Woooow.Thanks you.and can you tell me is there any good thing when i use __set in here and do i want to improve any code here ?

Comment: @MrPHP If it's good or not, I don't know. and the code is basically okay.

Comment: is it support for sql injection .? do i want to use placeholders ?

Comment: @MrPHP depends on what you insert: only your own data or also user data. If user data, you should escape your id (the table name you can't escape with placeholders)

Comment: @MrPHP As this answer solved your problem, consider upvoting and accepting it, by clicking on the large green tick mark (✔) under the answer's score.